# Difference between ForeignKey(User, unique=True) and OneToOneField

Tags: django, django-models

What is different between `models.ForeignKey(Modelname, unique=True)` and `models.OneToOneField` in Django?

Where should I use `models.OneToOneField` and `models.ForeignKey(Modelname, unique=True)`?

Comment: @alan Wasn't enough clarification available in other answers like this Alasdir's Answer clarify the concept very well

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A `OneToOneField` is very similar to a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`. Unless you are doing multiple table inheritance, in which case you have to use `OneToOneField`, the only real difference is the api for accessing related objects.

In the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#onetoonefield) it says:

> Conceptually, this is similar to a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`, but the "reverse" side of the relation will directly return a single object.

Let's show what that means with an example. Consider two models, `Person` and `Address`. We'll assume each person has a unique address.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.ForeignKey('Address', unique=True)

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

If you start with a person, you can access the address easily:

```
address = person.address
```

However if you start with an address, you have to go via the `person_set` manager to get the person.

```
person = address.person_set.get() # may raise Person.DoesNotExist
```

Now let's replace the `ForeignKey` with a `OneToOneField`.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.OneToOneField('Address')

class Address(models.Model):
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

If you start with a person, you can access the address in the same way:

```
address = person.address
```

And now, we can access the person from the address more easily.

```
person = address.person # may raise Person.DoesNotExist
```

Comment: might be worth noting that Django generates a following warning for ForeignKey fields with unique=True: "HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField"

Answer (score 1):

When you access a `OneToOneField` you get the value of the field you queried. In this example a book model's 'title' field is a `OneToOneField`:

```
>>> from mysite.books.models import Book
>>> b = Book.objects.get(id=50)
>>> b.title
u'The Django Book'
```

When you access a `ForeignKey` you get the related model object, which you can then preform further queries against. In this example the same book model's 'publisher' field is a `ForeignKey` (correlating to the `Publisher` class model definition):

```
>>> b = Book.objects.get(id=50)
>>> b.publisher
<Publisher: Apress Publishing>
>>> b.publisher.website
u'http://www.apress.com/'
```

With `ForeignKey` fields queries work the other way too, but they're slightly different due to the non-symmetrical nature of the relationship.

```
>>> p = Publisher.objects.get(name='Apress Publishing')
>>> p.book_set.all()
[<Book: The Django Book>, <Book: Dive Into Python>, ...]
```

Behind the scenes, book_set is just a `QuerySet` and can be filtered and sliced like any other `QuerySet`. The attribute name book_set is generated by appending the lower case model name to `_set`.
I hope this helps illustrate the differences between the relationships created.