# Django: Anonymous session & "temporary" one-to-one related model?

Tags: django, django-sessions

Currently, I have a `Cart` model for each registered `CustomUser` (OneToOne relation):

```py
class Cart(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, related_name='cart')
```

But now I have some requirement for anonymous user (guest). after looking for some articles, session seems to be required?

1. Simple database-based session.
2. How to let guest has a related temporary `GuestCart` model **when they need**:

   - Because I don't expect even a robot has a cart to waste resource.
   - So...may I `GuestCart.objects.create(session = request.session['cart'])   #just pseudo-code, I don't sure how to do this` **when a view is called** by the guest?
3. `GuestCart` would live for exactly 1 week (count from the `GuestCart` is **established**. Time won't updated for guest's activity), and should be deleted *automatically* when expired.

** Update @ 2015/3/21: currently, I add a new key `cart_id` into `request.session`, and not save session info into DB.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to support anonymous users i believe your `Cart` model class should looks like this;

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, blank=True, null=True, related_name='cart')
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40)

  class Meta:
    unique_together = ('user', 'session_key',)
```

Then you can retrieve the user cart with something like this:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    cart, created = Cart.objects.update_or_create(
        user = request.user,
        defaults = {'session_key': request.session.session_key}
    )
else:
    cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(
        session_key = request.session.session_key,
        defaults = {'user': None}
    )
```

and later on if the checkout process required registration you can always alter the cart and add the user.

Comment: The code means that when the user is authenticated you use `request.user`, when the user is anonymous you use `session_key`. About the 3rd requirement you can create a cron job executing `Cart.objects.filter(user=None, created_at__lt=week_ago).delete()` to remove the old carts. You should be aware that this approach is session based for the guest carts, which means that when a anonymous user start a new session, he will receive a new `cart`.

Comment: `Cannot assign None: "Cart.user" does not allow null values.`

Comment: Even if add a `null=True` to `Cart.user`, it still raise  `IntegrityError 
carts_cart.session_key may not be NULL` at `defaults = {'user': None}`

Comment: Your old schema had `unique=True` on the `user` field. I guess this can be the reason for the errors. Run `show create table myapp_cart` and check what's going on with the fields *(are the fields consistent with the current state of the model)*.

Comment: sorry, I just forgot to say that I've removed `unique=True`, but still got error. (BTW, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949077/difference-between-foreignkeyuser-unique-true-and-onetoonefield )

Comment: Removing `unique=True` from the field do not update the database schema. Have you tried running `makemigration` and `migrate` after that?

Comment: I guess it would be better to make another `GuestCart` model?

Comment: I don't think its better, that's why i suggested you such structure :). However later on I will try to make a simple demo to test the code.

Comment: Oops, `request.session` is `{'modified': False, 'serializer': <class 'django.core.signing.JSONSerializer'>, '_session_cache': {}, '_session_key': None, 'accessed': True}`, without `session_key`

Comment: I saw you accepted the answer, did you managed to make it work ? I wasn't able to spend more time on the problem these days? Let me know if the answer need some corrections.

Comment: Yes, now it can work, but I use `request.session['cart_id']` to save `cart.pk`, instead of add field into `Cart` due to some strange problems as I've described in these comments.